# Given a number, program must return the alphabet letter correspondent

Tags: code-golf, number

### The program

Given a number, program must return the alphabet letter correspondent.

### Rules

- The challenge here is to make it as short as possible, everyone knows it is a very easy program to do.
- The number is not zero-based, it means `1` is `A`, `2` is `B`, `3` is `C` and so it goes...
- Any language will be accepted.

Comment: I suspect the winning answer will be tiny.

Comment: I think my answer won

Comment: @BernaMariano What does "given a number" mean?

Comment: @toothbrush If Goku gives you a 3, use 3.

Comment: @BernaMariano Well, I'm not sure what you mean, but is [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/21448/15022) OK, then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## DC - 6 characters

*Full program* including input and output.

```
?64+af
```

save to file and run with `$ dc file`

Comment: 1 character shorter: `?64+P`

Comment: Typically: `dc -f file`

Answer (score 7):

### APL (4)

(Full program)

```
⎕⌷⎕A
```

Explanation:

`⎕` (user input) `⌷` (index) `⎕A` (alphabet)

(They're supposed to be boxes, it's not an encoding problem.)

Answer (score 7):

## Brainfuck, 107 bytes

```
>,----------[>++++++[-<------>],----------]<[<]>>[<--[->++++++++++<]>>]+++++++[-<+++++++++>]<-.>++++++++++.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <s>64 56</s> 50 bytes

*Thanks to Dorian for saving 3 bytes and inspiring 3 more*

```
,>,[<+[-<+>[-<]>>]<[<++<-]>++>>]<<+++[->+++++<]>+.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fx04n2kY7WtdG2w5IxNrZxdoA@do2urF22togHpADlAZygAAor633/7@hAQA)

### How it works

```
,>, Gets input
   [ if a two digit number
    <+[-<+>[-<]>>] Gets modulo 2 of first number plus 1
                  <[<++<-] Sets the fives cell to 2 if the first number is a 2
                          >++ Adds another 2 to the fives cell
                             >>]  Moves to cell after ones cell
                                <<+++ Adds 3 to fives cell
                                     [->+++++<] Multiply the fives cell by 5 and add it to the ones cell
                                               >+.  Add one and print
```

Comment: Can be made shorter. Instead of tens, use "fives". Increment the tens by two for each ten, then multiply by five. Saves 3 Bytes.
    `,>,[<[-<+>[-<]>>]>[>++>]<++[-<+++++>]]++++[-<++++>]<.`

Comment: Even more. By changing the 4*4 routine in the end to 3*5+1, you can use the fives and add them to the 3. It's a bit tricky to exit the if then, but it saves another 4 Bytes. `,>,[<[-<+>[-<]>>]<<<[->+<]>+>>]<<+++[->+++++<]>+.`

Comment: @Dorian Your second solution doesn't work for numbers over 20, but thanks for the bytes saved!

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Didn't test it well enough. I'm glad you repaired it.

Answer (score 2):

### R, 11 characters

```
LETTERS[x]
```

Usage:

```
LETTERS[21]
[1] "U"
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
"&++,@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X0lNW1vH4f9/QwA)

Takes advantage of the extra spaces at the end of a wrapping string literal by adding two spaces (`32*2 = 64`) to the inputted number to turn it into the corresponding alphabetic character. Funnily enough, if we use a implementation that doesn’t include the wrapping spaces, we can do `"&+.@` to add the `@` (64) to the number instead.

Answer (score 1):

### J, 7 characters

```
a.{~64+
```

Usage:

```
   a.{~64+1
A
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 20 characters

```
chr(($ARGV[0] + 64))
```

Verification :

```
risk@skynet:~/perl$ for x in {1..26}; do perl ./ord.pl $x; done;
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZrisk@skynet:~/perl$
```

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 34 bytes

```
sub("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",Ans,1
```

This is as short as it gets...

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 17 bytes

```
<?=chr(64+$argn);
```

Run s pipe with `-F`

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 4 bytes

```
64+c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/38xEO/n/fyMA)

Because, why not. Takes input implicitly, pushes `64` and adds it to the input number. Finally it converts the number to its ASCII-equivalent using `c`.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth - <s>5</s> 3 Bytes

```
@Gt
```

Saved two bytes thanks to ovs

Completely forgot about `t` and implicit `Q`

Explanation:

```
@    Index
 G   in alphabet of
  t  one less than
   Q Input (implicitly added to solve arity)
```

Comment: `@Gt` for [3 bytes](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%40Gt&input=26&debug=0)

Comment: @ovs Thanks. Forgot about `t` and implicit `Q`

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 6 bytes

```
n8:*+o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z/PwkpLO///fyMTAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes

```
c+64
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P1nbzOT///9GZgA)

Boring, but probably optimal. Adds 64 to the given number and converts it to ASCII. `!¡→'A` is cuter (awww, the exclamation marks are friends!) but one byte longer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 10 Bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/19BwVFBQ6GaS0FfQV1BW8Gayx7IclDQU9DjAhEQBoT@/9/QCAA)

```
A({/'+;?/@
```

Expanded:

```
  A ( {
 / ' + ;
? / @ . .
 . . . .
  . . .
```

This honestly took me way longer than it should have, as it's just 2 simple reflections.

---

The simplest version for this problem is only 2 bytes longer

```
  A ( {
 . . . .
? ' + ; @
 . . . .
  . . .
```

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell, <strike>19</strike> 18 bytes

-1 byte thanks to @mazzy lol
<strike>I don't think it'll get much shorter than this</strike>.

```
[char](64+"$args")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/Pzo5I7EoVsPMRFtJJbEovVhJ8/9/AA)

Takes input from a command line argument.

Comment: You can. Try this `[char](64+"$args")`. [:)](https://coub.com/view/1kgw3a)

Answer (score 1):

## Powershell 6, 17 bytes

```powershell
('@'..'Z')[$args]
```

Answer (score 0):

## q/k (7)

As partially applied composition:

```
10h$64+
```

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby 1.9 (10)

```
(x+64).chr
```

Reading from STDIN and printing to STDOUT:

```
$><<(gets.to_i+64).chr
```

Answer (score 0):

## Burlesque (6 characters)

Assuming the number is already on the stack:

```
64.+L[
```

(see [here](http://eso.mroman.ch/cgi/burlesque.cgi?q=3+64.%2BL%5b) in action.).

Does the usual: Add 64, convert to character based on ASCII value.

If number is supplied as a string via stdin to stdout (10 characters):

```
ri64.+L[sh
```

Alternative version without using ASCII value conversion:

```
'@'Zr@\/!!
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 9 bytes

```
chr(64+x)
```

#### Or, reading from stdin and printing to stdout: 21

```
print chr(64+input())
```

Comment: Submissions have to be full programs or functions, and your first solution is a "snippet". You should only include your second solution.

Answer (score 0):

## GolfScript, 7

```golfscript
64+]''+
```

#### Commentary

```golfscript
64    # corresponds to '@' in ASCII (65 is 'A')
+]    # add the input to 64. ']' is used for ASCII.
''+   # the conversion process
```

**[1 corresponds to A](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyAxCjY0K10nJys%3D)**

**[26 corresponds to Z](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyAyNgo2NCtdJycrCg%3D%3D)**

Comment: It can indeed: assuming that the only thing on the stack is the number from 1 to 26, you don't need the `[`.

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript, 25 chars

```
String.fromCharCode(66-x);
```

### PHP, 22 chars

```
echo chr(66-$argv[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

## Classic ASP (14 bytes):

```
<%=Chr(c+64)%>
```

*Expects `c` to hold the character number.*

Comment: `program must return` -> I see no program, I don't see `c` being initialized, I don't see anything returned/printed.

Comment: @RobIII OK; changed to Classic ASP. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Where does the value of `c` come from? You'd need something like `request.form("c")` or something (and the inevitable cast to int/long etc.).

Comment: @RobIII The question says "given". Perhaps we can ask for clarification?

Comment: I interpret this as "when the program is given" but asking for clarification won't hurt ;)

Answer (score 0):

**C#** 4,50KB (196 characters)

My first time here =)

```cs
using System; namespace W { class P { static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine(" abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".ToCharArray()[int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, don't forget the byte count of the program. Second, there are several ways of shortening this. First, remove all unnecessary whitespace (for example, the ` `s after the `" ",`s. You could split the string `" abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`. Also, rather than compile a list beforehand, it is much more efficient to choose the characters based off of ascii values.

Comment: Also: the contest explicitly mentions `The program`; this is not a complete program but (part of) a function. Other than that: drop the array/lookup! Ever heard of the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/)? ;-) And dont forget that, if you insist on a "lookup table", a string **is** an array of chars: `string a=" abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";` shortens your code massively.

Comment: You can drop the namespace entirely, use the `args` for input instead of `Console.readline`, shorten `args` to `a` and drop the `using System` and just write `System.Console.WriteLine`. The .ToCharArray() is also not required (a string is a char-array implicitly). Finally, the `WriteLine` can be shortened to `Write` since the challenge doesn't specify that the program needs to output a newline.

Comment: ...So your entry could be shortened to 112 chars (compiled size doesn't matter, "lose" the 4,50KB) if you incorporate all these tips: `class P{static void Main(string[] a){System.Console.WriteLine(" abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[int.Parse(a[0])]);}}`. The only thing left to do to "optimize" this code further is to drop the alphabet string and just use [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) as I did in [my entry](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/21463/14039) which will get you down to 88 :-)

Comment: Oh, and your entry states "196 characters"; I don't know how you counted (but I assume you looked at the filesize of the .cs file?): your entry is actually **162** chars when all **non-functional(!)** whitespace is removed: `using System;namespace W{class P{static void Main(string[] args){Console.WriteLine(" abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".ToCharArray()[int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())]);}}}`.

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 38 bytes

```
main = putChar $ ('a':['a'..'z']) !! c
```

Where `c` is the number.

Comment: There is a lot of unnecessary white space: `main=putChar$('a':['a'..'z'])!!c` works as well. However you can not assume input to be present in a certain variable, but then again returning from a function is acceptable, so `f c=('a':['a'..'z'])!!c` or equivalently `(('a':['a'..'z'])!!)` works.

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 87

```c#
class P{static void Main(string[]a){System.Console.Write((char)(int.Parse(a[0])+64));}}
```

Complete program (not some (part of a) "function" expecting foo to be bar to work), accepts command line parameter: `foo.exe 1` prints `A`, `foo.exe 16` prints `P`

## C#, 10

When I make the same assumptions as, for example, the 'code-golfers' that posted the [<s>VSCript</s> Classic ASP](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/21448/14039), [Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7326/14039), [Burlesque](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7318/14039), [Ruby](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7317/14039), [C](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7316/14039) solutions we can get it down to 10:

```c#
(char)x+64
```

"Assuming `x` is magically initialized / passed in / on the stack / whatever excuse" and the contest doesn't explicitly require me to print it, just "return" it (which most of the above solutions don't do, either).

Comment: I've changed my answer to a full Classic ASP example now.

Comment: Well, the author of the question did NOT specify how the number is given. "Given a number" is completely under-specified. Is it on stdin, is it a command line argument is it given somewhere else... You have no other choice than to make assumptions about how you get that number and how you return it.

Comment: @mroman See my comments on the [Classic ASP](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/21448/14039) and [C](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7316/14039) answers.

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 30 bytes

```
puts [expr [scan $argv %c]-64]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oLSkWCE6taKgSCG6ODkxT0ElsSi9TEE1OVbXzCT2////jgA)

Answer (score 0):

BrainFuck, 66

```
,>,----------[<[->++++++++++<]++++++[>+++++++<-]>>]++++[<++++>-]<.
```

Comment: Require number ends with \n(10) and mod 256 env

Comment: Please add some explanation in the body of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
ịØA
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///h7u7DMxz///9vCgA)

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 18 bytes

```
INPUT N?CHR$(N+64)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 15 bytes (as lambda function)

```java
n->(char)(n+64)
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LY5PC4JAEMXvfYpHp10WhSI8ZPYN8uIxOmyr1pqOoqsQ4We38Q/MMMyb3/BeoQft1U1GRfqZTKm7Djdt6bcDLLmszbXJEM8rYN66hRGsg2TI0sjN1TntrEEMQoSJvKuYSSlIBSc5hSvU9M@SoY0dapuiYiORuNbS6/7QcjXJ63ZxsNEhhL1Ex4CHUnI5Asm3c1nl173zG350JQmr9mfsFfkcTW65xukP)

## Java 8, 84 bytes (as full program)

```java
interface M{static void main(String[]a){System.out.printf("%c",new Byte(a[0])+64);}}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y0osS9TNL0jNy0rJ/v8/M68ktSgtMTlVwbe6uCSxJDNZoSw/M0UhNzEzTyO4pCgzLz06NlGzOriyuCQ1Vy@/tESvAChYkqahpJqspJOXWq7gVFmSqpEYbRCrqW1momldW/v//39DAwA)

Comment: This works only for single digit. Double digit input will fail. ex: give 10 as input and output still comes as A. You care considering charAt(0), for double digits, you have to consider 2 characters.

Comment: @BarathVutukuri Thanks, fixed!

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 11 bytes

```hs
(['@'..]!!)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzXyNa3UFdTy9WUVHzf25iZp6CrUJRamKKT56CnZ2tQkFpiXNGYpGCnkLaf8N/yWk5ienF/3UjnAMCAA) This anonymous function indexes into the string `"@ABCDEFG ..."`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Fortran (GFortran)](https://gcc.gnu.org/fortran/), 30 bytes

```
READ*,I
PRINT*,ACHAR(I+64)
END
```

My entry in the good ol' Fortran.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKilKzNNNT4Mw/v8PcnV00dLx5AoI8vQL0dJxdPZwDNLw1DYz0eRy9XP5/9/QAgA)

Answer (score 0):

## **FORTH 16 BYTES**

```
: n 64 + EMIT ;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
8 N
8 N H ok
5 N
5 N E ok
12 N
12 N L ok
12 N
12 N L ok
15 N
15 N O ok
23 N
23 N W ok
15 N
15 N O ok
18 N
18 N R ok
12 N
12 N L ok
4 N
4 N D ok
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 31 bytes

```
puts [format %c [incr argv 64]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oLSkWCE6Lb8oN7FEQTVZITozL7lIIbEovUzBzCQ29v///4YGAA)

Answer (score 0):

## Japt, 2 bytes

```
dI
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=ZEk=&input=OA==) or [test all numbers](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=ZEk=&input=WzEsMiwzLDQsNSw2LDcsOCw5LDEwLDExLDEyLDEzLDE0LDE1LDE2LDE3LDE4LDE5LDIwLDIxLDIyLDIzLDI0LDI1LDI2XQotbVA=)

Answer (score -1):

## PHP 442

```
$alphabet = Array('A' => 1,'B' => 2,'C' => 3,'D' => 4,'E' => 5,'F' => 6,'G' => 7,'H' => 8,
'I' => 9,'J' => 10,'K' => 11,'L' => 12,'M' => 13,'N' => 14,'O' => 15,'P' => 16,'Q' => 17,
'R' => 18,'S' => 19,'T' => 20,'U' => 21,'V' => 22,'W' => 23,'X' => 24,'Y' => 25,'Z' => 26
)

function testInputForAlphabetCharacter($input){
    for($index = 0; $index < count($alphabet); $i = $i + 1){
        if($alphabet[$index] == $input){
            echo($index);
        }
    }
}


$input = $_GET['input'];
testInputForAlphabetCharacter($input);
```

Comment: @scleaver... o_0

Comment: I agree with @IanBrindley, this is serious overkill... There's *no* chance of shrinking this down?

Comment: `echo chr(64+$input);`

Comment: this is as small as i could get it