# Exponential-ish number sequence

Tags: code-golf, sequence, kolmogorov-complexity

Your program must print out this exact sequence:

```
1
2
4
10
24
54
116
242
496
1006
2028
4074
8168
16358
32740
65506
131040
262110
NOPE!
```

As usual, shortest program wins. Standard code golf rules apply.

Comment: How did you come up with this sequence and why does it end where it does?

Comment: @dylnan It's your task to find the rule :)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder that's silly. As soon as anyone finds the rule it will be obvious in their code.

Comment: Why are you printing `NOPE!`? Once you have the sequence you can continue it.

Comment: IMO the `NOPE!` just makes each submission longer by about 10 bytes, and doesn’t serve any purpose when it comes to making the challenge more interesting.

Comment: @dylnan: it's the number of backslashes in the python string '\' before each call to repr on the previous value. I was messing around with successive repr calls and the nope was just there so I didn't hang the computer.

Comment: May we output an array instead of a newline separated string?

Comment: @Beefster so can we disregard the "NOPE!"?

Comment: By the way - welcome to PPCG! Next time you post a challenge, you can post a draft to the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) first, and the community will help you format it and iron out any bugs :)

Comment: @Shaggy I guess that's technically in the spirit of the challenge. I only say 'sequence'.

Comment: @Riker NOPE! I kinda want to see if anyone comes up with a clever way to represent it in fewer bytes, though that probably isn't possible.

Comment: Future me sees the error in past me's ways. The nope is not very interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGLOnline), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
1O'²∫ūF-«O"NOPE!
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=MU8lMjclQjIldTIyMkIldTAxNkJGLSVBQk8lMjJOT1BFJTIx,v=0.12)

Explanation:

```
1O                output 1
  '²∫             17 times do, pushing 1-indexed counter
     ū              calculate 2^pop
      F-            subtract from that the counter
        «           multiply by 2
         O          output
          "NOPE!    push "NOPE!", which gets printed at the end as implicit output hasn't been disabled. This gets pushed every iteration of the loop, to save a byte
```

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 51 bytes

```python
i=0;exec"print 2**i-i<<(i>0);i+=1;"*18;print"NOPE!"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PWwDq1IjVZqaAoM69EwUhLK1M308ZGI9POQNM6U9vW0FpJy9DCGiyr5Ocf4Kqo9P8/AA)

Notices that the formula is **2(2<sup>n</sup>-n)**, for all **n** except **0**.

Saved two bytes thanks to [Wheat Wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/wheat-wizard) (`i<<1-(i<1)` changed to `i<<(i>0)`, duh!).

---

#### [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 53 bytes

```python
i=0;exec"print[2**i-i<<(i>0),'NOPE!'][i>17];i+=1;"*19
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PWwDq1IjVZqaAoM68k2khLK1M308ZGI9POQFNH3c8/wFVRPTY6087QPNY6U9vW0FpJy9Dy/38A)

Comment: I wrote exactly the same `for i in range(18):print(2**i-i)*2-(i<1)
print"NOPE!"` solution, but was too late, it seems :)

Comment: [51](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PWwDq1IjVZqaAoM69EwUhLK1M308ZGI9POQNM6U9vW0FpJy9DCGiyr5Ocf4Kqo9P8/AA "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: @WheatWizard Thanks! That was the cleverish trick I was looking for!

Comment: Don't know if it helps but, **f(n)=2*(f(n-1)+n)** for all **n** except **0**

Comment: @WheatWizard Since this is kolmo-complexity, recursion should (theoretically) not be shorter

Comment: [54 using the OP's method](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9i22FYpJkaJK7UiNVmpoCgzr0ShWC85vzSvRCNY07rYNqE4wVpJy9CCCyyn5Ocf4Kqo9P8/AA "Python 2 – Try It Online"), but probably can't be golfed to be shorter than yours

Answer (score 6):

## Fortran 95, <s>82</s> 74 bytes

Compiled with `gfortran`, with the `-cpp` flag to enable preprocessing, or saving the file with `.F95` extension.

```
#define p print*,
program w
p 1
do i=1,17
p 2*(2**i-i)
enddo
p'NOPE!'
end
```

<s>Longest answer!</s> Not anymore! YAY!

Answer (score 5):

## [Emojicode](http://www.emojicode.org/), 96 bytes

```
1 2i⏩1 18✖2➖2.0i i 10NOPE!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83Nz8pMzk9J/f//w/z@xg/ze9s/zJ/R8GH@lIWGCkZAqinzUf9KQwVDC2SpR3OmGT2aNw2oAyjU32SkZ/Bh/qyGTIVMBUMgq7cTqm6Jn3@AqyKIARL8/x8A)

Comment: +1 for the  icon, will look forward to this language

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 20 bytes

```
17Rµ2*_×2“NOPE!”ṭ1;Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9qZWxsef//MTdSwrUyKl/DlzLigJxOT1BFIeKAneG5rTE7Wf//)

**Explanation**

```
17Rµ2*_×2“NOPE!”ṭ1;Y
17R                   range(17):[1,2,...17]
   µ                  new monadic link
    2*                exponentiate: [2*1, 2*2,...2*17]
      _               subtract: [2*1-1, 2*2-1,...2*17-17]
       ×2             times 2. Ḥ would need an additional syntax character but ×2 doesn't.
         “NOPE!”ṭ     append "NOPE!" to the above list
                 1;   prepend 1 to the above list
                   Y  join by newlines and implicitly print
```

**A recursive [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly) solution, 26 bytes**

```
’ß+_3$ḤµṖṖ$¡
18RÇ€Y⁷“NOPE!
```

Took the `Y⁷“NOPE!` trick from Jonathan Allan.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw8zD87XjjVUe7lhyaOvDndOASOXQQi5Di6DD7Y@a1kQ@atz@qGGOn3@Aq@L///8B)

Comment: @JonathanAllan [In this case it can't](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9qZWxsef//MTdSwrUyKl/huKTigJxOT1BFIeKAneG5rTE7Wf//). Since `Ḥ` is a monad Jelly applies it to the right argument of `_`.

Comment: Yeah I noticed :) -- you can use `⁸` but no save there either

Answer (score 2):

## [Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab.html) (R2016b), <s>71</s> 69 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Giuseppe (replace `2*(i-2)` by `2*i-4`)

This version prints exactly as required:

```
a=1;for i=1:18,fprintf('%d\n',a),a=2*a+max(2*i-4,0);end,disp('NOPE!')
```

## [Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab.html) (R2016b), <s>53</s> 51 bytes

This version prints the same numbers and the `NOPE!`, but with a different formatting:

```
a=1,for i=1:17,a=2*a+max(2*i-4,0),end,disp('NOPE!')
```

Comment: I think `max(2*(i-2),0)` is equivalent to `max(2*i-4,0)` which will save a byte or two

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```
X17LDoα·»"NOPE!"»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/wtDcxyX/3MZD2w/tVvLzD3BVVDq0@/9/AA)

**Explanation**

```
X                  # push 1
 17L               # push range [1 ... 17]
    D              # duplicate
     o             # raise 2 to the power of each
      α            # absolute difference
       ·           # times 2
        »          # join list on newlines
         "NOPE!"   # push this string
                »  # join stack on newlines
```

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript (ES2016), <s>58</s> <s>55</s> 54 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @l4m2*

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @user71546*

```js
for(i=0;i<18;l(2**i-i<<!!i++))l=console.log;l("NOPE!")
```

Uses the formula `2(2n-n)` for all `n ≠ 0` and `2n-n` for `n = 0`, based on @MrXcoders [Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/151907/70894)

### If returning an array of lines is allowed, <s>54</s> 52 bytes

```js
_=>[...""+1e19].map((_,i)=>i>18?"NOPE!":2**i-i<<!!i)
```

Comment: `l(i=1);while(i<18)` => `for(l(i=1);i<18;)`

Comment: Change `(2<<i)-i-i++` to `2**i-i++<<1` for 1 byte less ;)

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 19 bytes

```
l17:tWw-E"@]'NOPE!'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P8fQ3KokvFzXVckhVt3PP8BVUf3/fwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 23 bytes

```
18Çn2pZ¹*2Ãh1 ·+"
NOPE!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/39DicHueUUHUoZ1aRoebMwwVDm3XVuLy8w9wVfz/HwA)

---

## 24 bytes

```
17õ!²i½ í- m*2 ·+"
NOPE!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/39D88FbFQ5syD@1VOLxWVyFXy0jh0HZtJS4//wBXxf//AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>56</s> <s>51</s>  39 bytes

```r
cat(1,2*(2^(x=1:17)-x),"NOPE!",sep="
")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRMNQx0hLwyhOo8LW0MrQXFO3QlNHyc8/wFVRSac4tcBWiUtJ8/9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 19 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
1⁷17µ2*_µ€ḤY⁷“NOPE!
```

A full program printing the result to STDOUT.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/wUeN2Q/NDW4204g9tfdS05uGOJZFAoUcNc/z8A1wV////DwA)**

#### How?

```
1⁷17µ2*_µ€ḤY⁷“NOPE! - Main link: no arguments
1                   - literal 1 (printed as next byte starts a new leading constant chain)
 ⁷                  - literal newline (also printed for the same reason)
  17                - literal seventeen
    µ   µ€          - for €ach n in range -> [1,2,3,...,17]
     2              -   literal two
      *             -   raise to power n  -> [2,4,8,...,131072]
       _            -   subtract n        -> [1,2,5,...,131055]
          Ḥ         - double (vectorises) -> [2,4,10,...,262110]
           Y        - join with newlines (again this is printed, as above)
            ⁷       - literal newline (this is also printed for the same reason)
             “NOPE! - literal list of characters "NOPE!" (no trailing close quote required
                    -  at the end of a Jelly program)
                    - implicit print
```

Some alternatives exist for 19 bytes, like

```
‘Ṅ+⁴2*$_$€ḤY⁷“NOPE!
```

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 89 bytes

```
@echo 1
@set/ap=2
@for /l %%i in (0,2,32)do @call echo %%p%%&set/ap+=p+%%i
@echo NOPE!
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, 42 bytes

```
say for 1,(map 2*(2**$_-$_),1..17),"NOPE!"
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVIhLb9IwVBHIzexQMFIS8NIS0slXlclXlPHUE/P0FxTR8nPP8BVUen//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDAE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), 57 bytes

```
00000000: 04c1 4101 4331 0042 b1fb 5303 94f2 3bff  ..A.C1.B..S...;.
00000010: c696 9850 2c52 6eb1 471a fa1b 9646 9447  ...P,Rn.G....F.G
00000020: f595 e73d bc73 1f27 5fc5 eed5 f0b1 2ab2  ...=.s.'_.....*.
00000030: d8e2 3f3f ff00 5745 00                   ..??..WE.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc@9SkRBDAXg3qc4nSByyPzd2VmRRUW3FS0s5WbuxEZtZJ//mtW1MkUICXyc6EH1fbwdPtZVTrWF5B6Qg3hLKUAkR2gwRUmS0LJFJDUDyBveBd6SzySvePYrBDf61Ca0TRHEXiKmoa7VMMPmoGhT9mvO9Wjw8fLpk3sf@MD9yYhuWGkFo6YF2mtCsFhRrPtuLAUmTsZZ449xzS@evx4NXvzlSG4sm@FpLRnMRFBqLv4Q/he525Ev91zXbw)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 10, <s>94</s> 80 bytes

```java
a->{var r="";for(int i=0;i<18;)r+=(i<1?1:2)*((1<<i)-i++)+"\n";return r+"NOPE!";}
```

Using the formula from Herman Lauenstein's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/151941/79343).

Thanks to Kevin Cruijssen for golfing 14 bytes.

Try it online [here](https://tio.run/##LY4xb8IwEIVn51dcPdm1EhEmVCft1IGhtBISC3S4hoCOBic6O5EqlN@eGoXtnk7vfd8FB0wvx9@p638aqqBq0Hv4QHJwSwS5UPMJqxrW9yi2gcmdoVO7lo7QapuIMRE@YIjVNRCUMGH6ehuQgUsp7allFUeAyoWlIl9ZzaZU8XrLX5b6Wam8KEinZIw28uCk5Tr07ICN3Hx@vT9JO04iUh52D9Jwp1@jo5qF9t@AfPZ6dvzzob5mbR@yLj6DoqxTrm8aPeuO0z8).

Ungolfed version:

```java
a -> { // lambda taking an unused null parameter
    var r = ""; // we build the output as a String
    for(int i = 0; i < 18; ) // generate the sequence
        r += (i < 1 ? 1 : 2) * ((1 << i) - i++) + "\n"; // append 2*(2^i-i) for n > 0, 2^i-i for n = 0
    return r + "NOPE!"; // return the constructed sequence, with NOPE! appended
}
```

Comment: Oh `var o=System.out;`. I need to remember that one! In this case it's shorter to return a String though: [Try it online **80 bytes**.](https://tio.run/##LY4xb8IwEIVn51dcPdm1EhEmVCft1IGhtBISC3S4hoCOBic6O5EqlN@eGoXtnk7vfd8FB0wvx9@p638aqqBq0Hv4QHJwSwS5UPMJqxrW9yi2gcmdoVO7lo7QapuIMRE@YIjVNRCUMGH6ehuQgUsp7allFUeAyoWlIl9ZzaZU8XrLX5b6Wam8KEinZIw28uCk5Tr07ICN3Hx@vT9JO04iUh52D9Jwp1@jo5qF9t@AfPZ6dvzzob5mbR@yLj6DoqxTrm8aPeuO0z8)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Right. I wasn't sure if this was allowed since the question states "print" and almost all answers print explicitly.

Comment: Well, it also states program, in which case `interface M{static void main(String[]a){...}}` is missing. ;p Since program/function, print/return, and flexible I/O are default when undefined explicitly I usually use that. If the challenge would have stated something alone the lines of "Create a program (no function) that prints the following exactly to STDOUT." I would follow that, but since it's only loosely mentions "program" and "print" without any explicit rules I'll just use the default, in which case a lambda function returning a String (or char-array for all I care) is fine. :)

Comment: In almost all languages (especially golfing languages), full programs or functions are similar / same byte-count, and printing is done implicitly (or with Python `print` is shorter than `return`), etc. Which is why most languages indeed print. (PS: With older challenges before these defaults were properly defined you will see a lot of full programs, even for Java, and challenges almost always mention program in the description. I usually answer both a program and function in that case, [like this answer I recently posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/159686/52210).)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks for your detailed explanation. I will keep this in mind for my answers in the future.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 61 bytes

```
i=0
x=1
print 1
exec"x*=2;print x;x+=i;i+=1;"*17
print"NOPE!"
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PWgKvC1pCroCgzr0TBkCu1IjVZqULL1sgaIlJhXaFtm2mdqW1raK2kZWgOUajk5x/gqqj0/z8A)

[Just search OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%202%204%2010%2024%2054%20116%20242%20496%201006%202028%204074%208168%2016358%2032740%2065506%20131040%20262110&sort=&language=english&go=Search)

Comment: That OEIS search reveals a duplicate entry in OEIS.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen They are not the same. One of the entries starts `1 2 4`, while the other starts `1 2 2 4`.

Comment: You are absolutely right! I even tried editing A132824 to make it a duplicate of A132732, but of course and fortunately that edit was not approved in there. Now I try to just mention in A132824 that a(n) = A132732(n-1) except for initial terms.

Answer (score 0):

## C,  <s>71</s>   <s>70</s>  68 bytes

*Thanks to @Mr. Xcoder for saving three bytes!*

```
f(n){for(n=-1;++n<18;)printf("%d\n",((1<<n)-n)<<!!n);puts("NOPE!");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI0@zOi2/SCPPVtfQWls7z8bQwlqzoCgzryRNQ0k1JSZPSUdDw9DGJk9TN0/TxkZRMU/TuqC0pFhDyc8/wFVRSdO69j9QsUJuYmaehiZXNZcCEKRpaFpz1f4HAA)

Comment: [70 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI0@zOi2/SCPPVtfQWls7z8bQwlqzoCgzryRNQ0k1JSZPSUdDw9DGJk9TN0/TxkYjz85AU9O6oLSkWEPJzz/AVVFJ07r2P1C5Qm5iZp6GJlc1lwIQpGloWnPV/gcA) using the latest edit of my Python answer

Comment: `<<!!n` saves two bytes instead of `<<(n>0)`

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 50 bytes

```hs
(unlines$show<$>1:[2*(2^n-n)|n<-[1..17]])++"NOPE!"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyflfbBvzX6M0LyczL7VYpTgjv9xGxc7QKtpIS8MoLk83T7Mmz0Y32lBPz9A8NlZTW1vJzz/AVVHpf25iZp6CrUJBaUlwSZFC8f9/yWk5ienF/3WTCwoA)

Comment: `unlines(` instead of `(unlines$` saves a byte.

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language](http://reference.wolfram.com) , 82 bytes

```
DifferenceRoot[Function[{y,n},{4-2 n-2 y[n]+y[1+n]==0,y[1]==1,y[2]==2}]]/@Range@18
```

This is actually a holonomic sequence whose solution was obtained from

```
f = FindSequenceFunction[{1, 2, 4, 10, 24, 54, 116, 242, 496, 1006}]
```

> ```
> DifferenceRoot[Function[{y,n},{4 - 2 n - 2 y[n] + y[1 + n] == 0, y[1] == 1, y[2] == 2}]]
> ```

I don't know why the `NOPE!` is needed as the sequence does continue

```
f[19]
```

> ```
> 524252
> ```

Comment: "NOPE" is sill required though.

Answer (score 0):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), <s>92</s> 65 bytes

```
import StdEnv
Start=("1\n",[(2*(2^n-n),'
')\\n<-[1..17]],"NOPE!")
```

Trivia: The type that is actually being printed is `(String, [(Int, Char)], String)`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85JTcz7n5ufUpqTqpCbmJn3PzO3IL@oRCG4JMU1r4wruCSxqMRWQ8kwJk9JJ1rDSEvDKC5PN09TR51LXTMmJs9GN9pQT8/QPDZWR8nPP8BVUUnz//9/yWk5ienF/3U9ff67VOYl5mYmAzlJAA)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP 5.6+, 65 bytes

```
<?=1,"\n";for($i=0;$i++<17;){echo 2*(2**$i-$i),"\n";}echo"NOPE!";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt7WUEcpJk/JOi2/SEMl09bAWiVTW9vG0Nxaszo1OSNfwUhLw0hLSyVTVyVTE6KyFiSu5Ocf4KqoZP3/PwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), <s>97</s> 83 bytes

```
	OUTPUT =1
I	X =X + 1
	OUTPUT =LT(X,18) 2 * (2 ^ X - X) 	:S(I)
	OUTPUT ='NOPE!'
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9M/NCQgNETB1pDLkzNCwTZCQVvBkAsu6hOiEaFjaKGpYKSgpaBhpBCnEKGgqxChqcBpFazhqYlQqO7nH@CqqM7l6ufy/z8A)

I'm still not really sure why I had two counters going; I only needed one.

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 18 bytes

```
Ｅ¹⁸Ｉ⎇ι⊗⁻Ｘ²ιι¹NOPE!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM3sUDD0EJHwTmxuEQjJLUoL7GoUiNTR8ElvzQpJzVFwzczr7RYIyC/PLVIw0hHIVMThIGEoSYQWHNBDFHy8w9wVVTStP7//79uWQ4A) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
 ¹⁸                 Literal 18
Ｅ                   Map over implicit range
         ²          Literal 2
          ι         Current value
        Ｘ           Exponentiate
           ι        Current value
       ⁻            Subtract
      ⊗             Double
            ¹       Literal 1
     ι              Current value
    ⎇               Ternary
   Ｉ                Cast to string
                    Implicitly print on separate lines
             NOPE!  Literal string
                    Implictly print
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 47 bytes

```hs
unlines[show$2*(2^x-x)-0^x|x<-[0..17]]++"NOPE!"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyflfbBvzvzQvJzMvtTi6OCO/XMVIS8MorkK3QlPXIK6ipsJGN9pAT8/QPDZWW1vJzz/AVVHpf25iZp5tQWlJcEmRQvH/f8lpOYnpxf91kwsKAA)

Answer (score 0):

## Bash, 67 characters

```
echo 1
for((i=0;i++<17;));do
echo $((2*(2**i-i)))
done
echo "NOPE!"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I1/BkCstv0hDI9PWwDpTW9vG0NxaU9M6JZ8LLKmioWGkBURambqZmpqaXCn5eakQGSU//wBXRaX//wE)

Comment: [-11 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I1/B0Dotv0hDo8LWyLrSxtDcukLbtkLbSKtSW1tT07paAaxGpcK61hrM8vMPcFX8/x8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 48 bytes

```
END{for(;i++<17;){print 2*(2**i-i)}print"NOPE!"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/f1c@lOi2/SMM6U1vbxtDcWrO6oCgzr0TBSEvDSEsrUzdTsxYsoOTnH@CqqFT7/z8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Recursiva](https://github.com/officialaimm/recursiva), 23 bytes

```
E++A1mB17"D~^2a"A"NOPE!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pNLi0qzixL/P/fVVvb0TDXydBcyaUuzihRyVHJzz/AVfH/fwA)

```
E++A1mB17"D~^2a"A"NOPE!  - Implicitly print the evaluated value
E                        - Join with newline
 +                       - Concatenate
  +A1mB17"D~^2a"         - [1, 2, 6, 14... 262142]
  +                      - Concatenate
   A1                    - Listify 1 [1]
     mB17"D~^2a"         - [2,6,14... 262142]
     m                   - map with
      B17                - [1,2...17]
         "D~^2a"         - Function 2(2^n - 1)
                A"NOPE!  - Listify ["NOPE!"]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 35 bytes

```perl6
{1,{2*(2**++$-++$)}.../21/,'NOPE!'}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7X1qcqlBmppdszZVbqaCWnJ@SqmD7v9pQp9pIS8NIS0tbW0UXiDVr9fT09I0M9XXU/fwDXBXVa//rFSdWKqTlFymA9Gho/gcA)

```perl6
{  # bare block lambda

  1,     # start the sequence with `1`

  {  # bare block used to generate values

    2*(
      2 ** ++$ # 2 to the power of an incrementing state variable
      -
      ++$      # incrementing anonymous state variable
    )
  }

  ...          # keep generating values until

  /21/,        # it generates a value that contains '21'

  'NOPE!'      # continue sequence with string 'NOPE!'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 43 bytes

```ruby
->{[1]+(1..17).map{|i|2*(2**i-i)}<<"NOPE!"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf16462jBWW8NQT8/QXFMvN7GguiazxkhLw0hLK1M3U7PWxkbJzz/AVVGp9n9BaUmxQlp07H8A)

A lambda returning an array of integers (and one string). Breaking out 1 into a special case was pretty cheap, and didn't hurt my brain at all!

Answer (score 0):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), 530 bytes

```
{iiiii}dc{dddd}ic{iiii}c{dddd}c{iiii}iic{dddd}ddc{iiii}dcdc{dddd}iic{iiii}ciic{dddd}ddc{iiii}iiicdc{dddd}ddc{iiii}dcciiiiic{dddd}ddddc{iiii}ciicddc{dddd}c{iiii}iiciiiiicdddc{dddd}ddddc{iiii}dcdcciiiiiic{dddd}ddddc{iiii}cddciiciiiiiic{dddd}ddddddc{iiii}iicddddc{i}dddcdddc{dddd}ddc{iiii}iiiiiic{d}iiiciiiiiciic{dddd}ddddddc{iiii}dciiiiicdddciiciiic{dddd}ddddddc{iiii}icdciiiiicdddcddddc{dddd}iic{iiii}iiiicdccdddddciiiiiic{dddd}ddddc{iiii}dciicddcdciiiicddddc{dddd}iic{iiii}ciiiicddddcdccdc{dddd}iic{{i}ddd}ddcicic{d}dc{ddd}ddddddc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVBbDoAgDDuRhzKrxn37aTg7MjrnDEhCwtbHVrCt2PU8llovtVMgF9opKr1RvPRK1WvAO5BQhGRktRu8JJU@M/qBmAMwjCYbwKiwNYjP7NrrkWc4rSdeWf8z4Q1AbY/CYu6FtCap04mSeXgnxi8SFKHqLxr8q8iYGiXE7BLMuBay7WnZCD6b1noD)